# Dynamic extent for converting TIFF to mbtiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, geotiff-tiff, mbtiles

I am trying to convert some `.tif` files to .mbtiles from the Python console in QGIS. The .tif files are in the TIFF folder and the converted .mbtiles are to be saved in the new folder. I have tried the following script

```
import os

from qgis.core import *

import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

input_folder = 'C:\\tiff'
output_folder = 'C:\\mbtiles'

os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
epsg_code = 'EPSG:3857'

for filename in os.listdir(input_folder):
    if filename.endswith('.tif'):
        input_raster = os.path.join(input_folder, filename)
        output_name = os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.mbtiles'
        output_mbtiles = os.path.join(output_folder, output_name)
    
    rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(input_raster, "Standard raster layer")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer, False)
    extent = rlayer.extent()
    
    processing.run("qgis:tilesxyzmbtiles", {
        'EXTENT': '{},{},{},{} [{}]'.format(extent.xMinimum(), extent.yMinimum(), extent.xMaximum(), extent.yMaximum(), epsg_code)',
        'ZOOM_MIN': 12, 
        'ZOOM_MAX': 22, 
        'DPI': 100,
        'BACKGROUND_COLOR': QColor(0, 0, 0, 0),
        'TILE_FORMAT': 0,
        'QUALITY': 75,
        'METATILESIZE': 4,
        'OUTPUT_FILE': output_mbtiles
    })
```

When I run the script, my QGIS is getting hanged when it is in the processing stage. How to solve this?